# locale: What is the LANGUAGE variable used for? (and when?)

Tags: linux, unix, language, locale

I am trying to understand the locales used in Linux. On my Ubuntu 11.10 system `locale` puts out the following:

```
LANG=en_DK.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_DK.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_DK.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY="en_DK.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_PAPER="en_DK.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_DK.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_DK.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_DK.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_DK.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_DK.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

(`en_dk` is for using international day format, continental European number formatting (1.234,56) etc.)

I think I understand what the `LC_*` family does, that `LANG` is the fallback if one of them is not set and that LC_ALL sets all of the `LC_*` variables to its value.

What I don't know yet, is what **`LANGUAGE`** is used for. The notation `en_GB:en` reminds me of the `Accept-Language` HTTP header. With the settings above it would mean, British English is used, if a translation for it exists. Otherwise any existing English translation (en_US, en_AU, ..., whatever) would be used.

Am I right so far?

Also what programs actually obey the `LANGUAGE` setting? In how far is it different from `LC_MESSAGES`?

Unfortunately, `man locale` only documents the `LC_*` family. And searching the web for 'linux locale LANGUAGE' or similar is a mute point. (Of course language is a word often used when talking about locales, and it may also be shown just in the output of `locale` without being discussed).

Does anybody of you can help me out there?

Answer (score 5):

It overrides to locale given in `$LC_ALL` [**with regards to gettext message catalogs**](http://lists.debian.org/debian-i18n/2005/11/msg00019.html). Otherwise, it's not used.

Comment: Interesting. However to be precise: It overrides all `LC_` variables and `LANG` for gettext (according to the post you linked). This is important to note as `LC_ALL` is usually not set by default.

Comment: Great! Thank you, @zpea and Ignacio! That cleared up things a lot for me.